# How to check for wrapping errors?

Tags: go

Go has the function [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) to check for errors. My problem is, that the `target` argument of `errors.Is` is a value instead of a type. I would like to create an error, which wraps another error using [`fmt.Errorf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Errorf) and `%w`. But I can not define a constant of this wrapping error for `errors.Is`, because the wrapping error is never constant, because the wrapped error always differs. How does this fit together?

Comment: basically, you implement `errors.Is` on the custom error type, as shown in the duplicate. In the implementation, you can assert that the error is of the same type as the receiver and/or use any logic that makes sense to your use case.

Comment: @blackgreen I can not implement `errors.Is`, because `target` is a value and not a type. That is the essence of this question. I think the person, who has closed this questions, was unable to understand that.

Comment: I closed the question. I advise to edit it to include some snippet that demonstrates the issue. It doesn't help to say that "target is a value" because anything that you pass to errors.Is will be a value.

Comment: @blackgreen I do not talk about `err`! I talk about **`target`**! And **`target`** can not be a value in case of a wrapping error. I need to pass the type of **`target`** to `errors.Is`.

Comment: How about making a example code for your question?